# I'm trying to make my 2-D Array program to get the largest element in each row but its not working

Tags: c++

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int rows = 2;
const int cols = 6;

void CheckRow(int x[][6], int rows){

        int highestr = 0;

        int r = 0, c = 0;
        for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
                cout << "ROW " << r + 1 << ": ";
                for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
                cout << x[r][c] << " ";
                cout << endl;
        }
> End of PRINTING THE CONTENTS

> THE CODE BELOW MUST CHECK FOR THE GREATEST VALUE IN A ROW, BUT IT WONT GIVE ME THE EXACT RESULTS AS IT SHOULD DISPLAY

        for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
                for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
                if (x[r][c] > highestr){
                        highestr += x[r][c];
                        cout << " Greatest Number: " << highestr;
                        cout << endl;
                }
        }
}

int main()
{
        int temps[rows][cols] =
        {
                { 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 },
                { 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 }
        };

        CheckRow(temps, 2);

        cout << endl << endl;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm trying to find the greatest value of a column..

Comment: For example
I have

1 , 2   // SHOULD DISPLAY 2 SINCE IT IS THE GREATEST VALUE
3 , 4   // SHOULD DISPLAY 4 SINCE IT IS THE GREATEST VALUE

Comment: highestr += x[r][c]; // this is not correct!  SImply do: highestr=x[r][c]

Comment: Please edit your question so that readers can find your questions in the first lines.

Comment: @KaustavRay I tried your code highestr=x[r][c], it displayed on the output of the program the whole elements in each array next to it Greatest Number: (a number)..

For example if I have { {1,2,3,4,5}, {4,3,2,1,6} };

I get the following:

Greatest Number: 1
Greatest Number: 2
Greatest Number: 3
Greatest Number: 4
Greatest Number: 5
Greatest Number: 4
Greatest Number: 3
Greatest Number: 2
Greatest Number: 1
Greatest Number: 6

Comment: @Jon I'm new to this :P I really don't know how to edit the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
{
         for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
         {
            if (x[r][c] > highestr)
            {
                    highestr = x[r][c];
            }
         }
         cout << " Greatest Number: " << highestr;
         cout << endl;
         highestr=0; // considering every element in your 2D array is greater than 0
}
```

Comment: You should understand the code properly than just using it ! Thanks :)